# On updating a mobile application, user should stay logged in or not if mandatory fields for signup/signin are changed?

Tags: manual-testing, mobile

While testing installation and update of a mobile application, i came up with a scenario, i.e.

i have installed application in mobile and i am already logged in to the application using valid credentials.
Now, As the flow of signup/sign-in is completely changed, when i am updating it with new version, should i stay logged-in or not in the application. what is the correct behavior?

Comment: Login session should remain unharmed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This something the business should decide. There are no lists of best practises.

As a tester you should not make up new requirements, you should signal that this could be an issue. Depending on effort and value the business should decide to implement it or not.

In this case as user, I would like it to stay logged in, because loggin in costs me time. But as a product owner it would depend on how easy this is to implement, couple of hours, sure, but couple of days, then maybe I would think wasting a couple of seconds of user time is acceptable.